# Push notification plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap-2.5.0 is not working

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I am trying to enable push notifications on my cordava iOS application.

I am following this tutorial : [Apple Push Notifications with PhoneGap](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/#comment-13566) .

The sample code on it works well but the problem is it uses and old version of cordova (2.1.0).

When i try to use the latest version 2.5.0 there are some problems.

1) There is no JSONKit.m/h class in the Cordova project. The pushnotifications plugin seems to need this class to work. However if i comment the line where this class is imported i solve the error of the non existing file. However i get some warnings...

2) After i ve commented the `#import <Cordova/JsonKit.h>` line the pushnotifications work only when the application is on the background. If the app is on the foreground and i send a push , the app with crash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cordova 2.4+ doesn't have JSONKit.

What you should do is change this line :

```
#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>
```

to

```
#import <Cordova/CDVJSON.h>
```

and it should work.