# phonegap push notification showing errors in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I'm incorporating the phonegap plugin for push notifications into my phonegap app but was receiving an error in my consol saying that `#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>` was wrong and the file couldn't be found. So going off this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357687/push-notification-plugin-for-cordova-phonegap-2-5-0-is-not-working) I was able to resolve the error but now its coming up with two addition warnings.

`NSString* uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];` *uniqueIdentifier in depreciated*

and 

`NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.pushNotification.notificationCallback(%@);", [userInfo cdvjk_JSONString]];` *instance method -cdvjk JSONString not found*

Has anyone come across this before? I'm using phonegap 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The first error is due to UUIDs being deprecated, unless you fix that warning your app will never be accepted into the app store. The fix is easy, replace `[[UIDevice ...] ...]` with:

```
NSString *uuid = [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier]
```

For the second issue, change `cdvjk_JSONString` to `JSONString`, this will be resolved in the next release of Cordova / PhoneGap.

Comment: the JSONString change took care of the warning but when I change the UIDevice to what you mentioned above, I get a semantic issue, saying that i'm using an undeclared identifier. I'm not an Obj-C programer so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: `ASIdentifierManager` is  `Available in iOS 6.0 and later`, so this solution is not apt for >iOS6.